# React component does not work anymore when using firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have the following react component:

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import PostPreview from '../PostPreview/PostPreview'
import { getPosts } from '../../services/postService'
import './postPreviewList.css'

export default class PostPreviewList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            id: this.props.id,
            posts: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        getPosts(this.state.id).then(posts => {
            this.setState({ posts })
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="posts mw-1200 m-auto d-flex justify-content-between">
                {this.state.posts && this.state.posts.map(post => (
                    <PostPreview key={post._id} post={post} />
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Everything works fine when I run my app using `npm start`. Now I wanted to deploy it with firebase. Therefore I built it but when I try to run it locally (firebase serve --only hosting) this component (and all others that are similar) stop working. There are two problems:

Iterating over arrays in firebase does not work with map so I changed it to

```
{this.state.posts && Object.keys(this.state.posts).map(function(key, index) {
   <PostPreview key={this.state.posts[key]._id} post={this.state.posts[key].post} />
})}
```

but now I get this error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

Also, if I print the `this.state.posts` array it is empty even though it should contain several elements. I don't understand why this problem only appears when using firebase.